# Why do typescript promise have void

Tags: typescript

I was going through this blog on the web to create [full stack app using typescript](https://dev.to/nuclight/setting-up-fullstack-typescript-app-1bbe)

Here he have used void like this

```
export const start = (port: number): Promise<void> => {
    const server = http.createServer(app);

    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        server.listen(port, resolve);
    });
};
```

I am not sure why they/he have used void here? void generally means that function won't return anything.

whereas I think promise will always return something (i.e it will either resolve or reject).

So what's the purpose of using void here?

Comment: What type do you expect there if not `void`?

Answer (score 1):

The type refers to the value that the promise resolves into. If it resolves into nothing, the type is void. For example:

```js
new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("hello");   // resolves into a string
});

new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(true);   // resolves into a boolean
});

new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();   // resolves into undefined/nothing/void
});
```

Presumably the `server.listen()` method doesn't call the callback with any arguments so the promise's type is void.